# Python thinks my List is a Tuple?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, attributes, tuples

I have a list that is called `step_segment`. It should never be a tuple.

When I press "7" in my `main` program. I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\programming\python\new_globals.py", line 205, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\programming\python\new_globals.py", line 203, in main
    pick_random(STATS, step_segment, seen, master)
  File "G:\programming\python\new_globals.py", line 125, in pick_random
    step_segment, STATS = take_step(step_segment, STATS)
  File "G:\programming\python\new_globals.py", line 69, in take_step
    step_segment.append(STATS)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The error only occurs when `pick_random()` is called:

```
def pick_random(STATS, seen, master):
    step_segment = []
    #if len(seen) >= 256:
    #   return seen, master
    while (len(step_segment)) < 128:
        step_segment, STATS = take_step(step_segment, STATS)
        if STATS[5] == "B":     # when there's a battle:
            randy = random.choice([0,1])
            if randy == 1:      # choose randomly between G and B
                step_segment = do_fight(step_segment, STATS)
            else:
                step_segment = do_glitch(step_segment, STATS)
            seen = seen + [STATS[0],STATS[5]]
    #if step_segment not in master:
        master.append(step_segment)
    time = get_frames(step_segment)
    print seen
    print time
    #return pick_random(STATS, seen, master)
    return seen, master
```

Full source: http://pastebin.com/fZgqtxZn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`do_flight()` returns a 2-tuple:

```
return step_segment, STATS
```

which you fail to unpack:

```
step_segment = do_fight(step_segment, STATS)
```

After this, `step_segment` becomes a tuple.

You probably meant to write

```
step_segment, STATS = do_fight(step_segment, STATS)
```

By way of general advice, you might want to keep your method signatures consistent to avoid this type of errors and/or learn a bit of object-oriented programming so that you don't have to keep passing the same variables everywhere.

Comment: That's right. The only problem with OOP is I have no idea what to make into Classes; I find myself asking, "Is a 'Step' a class?', 'is a segment a class?' - I simply cannot find the answer anywhere. I've read many books on the issue but I cannot get my head round it for my problem...